# Spacing after input elements with webkit appearance disabled

Tags: html, css

When I disable the wekbit-appearance of input elements, Chrome improperly sizes their parents.

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/umttuxm8/

Each of the intermediate divs (the ones with no classes) have a height of 24 px, despite having children with heights 20 px and 0 px; none of the elements have any margins, padding, or borders. The difference of height between the parents and child elements is always 4px per child input element.

How do I remove the 4 extra pixels of space?

The specific CSS I uses to disable the default input rendering was

```
input[type="radio"] {
     -webkit-appearance:none;
     margin:0;
}
```

EDIT: I am using Chrome; only Chrome and Safari support -webkit AFAIK, so other browsers may have trouble.

Comment: I have gotten it to work by changing using "visibility:none" on the input elements and giving them labels, but would prefer to understand/remove the inherit spacing.

Comment: Since you don't ask a specific question I am a little confused on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @crazymatt My bad.  I clarified what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: interesting issue you are having. You know that if you apply a height:20px to the DIV thats not using a class name they space will be removed?

Comment: Yes. I am merely curious/confused to the spacing; it appears to work similar to a margin but is not listed on any of the element's styling, including the user agent stylesheets. I am fairly certain the spacing is dependent upon the -webkit-appearance property specifically.